# Utilizing custom fonts with jspdf (React js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, frontend

I have been trying to incorporate the custom fonts which are used in my capstone project website for jspdf. I have tried and experimented for long hours and have exhausted all my options.

Thing I tried:

- Consulted various stackoverflow questions and various pointers provided
- Used various base64 encoders suggested on forums
- Tried a different custom font
- Tried removing bad/unnecessary characters from base64 encoded font (.ttf to base64)

Custom fonts:

The custom fonts are from google fonts:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Mono&family=Varela+Round&family=Maven+Pro&family=Kalam&display=swap
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caprasimo
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lilita+One
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest+Guy
```

jspdf version is: 2.5.1

Code that does not work:

```
const encfontpath = '../../../../../assets/fonts/Caprasimo/Caprasimo-Regular.txt'; // this is base64 encoded font
const cencfontpath = encfontpath.replace(/[=+/\\r\\n]/g,''); // remove bad characters from base64

pdfstory.setFontSize(20);
pdfstory.addFileToVFS(cencfontpath, 'Caprasimo');
pdfstory.addFont('Caprasimo.ttf', 'Caprasimo', 'normal');
pdfstory.setFont('Caprasimo');
```

Error:

```
console.js:20 jsPDF PubSub Error Font is not stored as string-data in vFS, import fonts or remove declaration doc.addFont('Caprasimo.ttf'). Error: Font is not stored as string-data in vFS, import fonts or remove declaration doc.addFont('Caprasimo.ttf').
    at Object.<anonymous> (ttfsupport.js:69:1)
    at C.publish (jspdf.js:70:1)
    at Object.Pe (jspdf.js:2446:1)
    at E.y.addFont (jspdf.js:4932:1)
    at handlePrintButtonClick (CreateBook.jsx:149:1)
```

In addition, I am having this error: the font 'font-name' contains a bad \BBox.                             Any help and additional pointers is greatly appreciated.